# Как получить прошлый месяц?

Tags: javascript

Есть рабочий код, который, отнимает от сегодняшнего, 1 месяц `somedate.setMonth(somedate.getMonth() - 1);` и показывает прошлый, работает со всеми датами кроме,

если сегодня 31 число (31 марта, 31 мая, 31 июля, 31 октября, 31 декабря) и число дней предыдущего месяца меньше 31-го дня, то месяц остаётся прежним.

```
var somedate = new Date();
console.log(somedate);
somedate.setMonth(somedate.getMonth() - 1);
console.log(somedate);
somedate.setDate(1);
console.log(somedate);
document.getElementById("fromdateinput").value = (somedate).format("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

> Tue Oct 31 2017 22:56:23 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
>
> Sun Oct 01 2017 22:56:23 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
>
> Sun Oct 01 2017 22:56:23 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))

Я конечно могу создать исключения для этих дат, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему так получается и и есть ли другие способы решения.

Comment: Что, в Вашем понимании, означает "отнять от даты один месяц"? "Один месяц" это вообще сколько?

Comment: Это особенности такие... лучше делайте исключение..... либо определяйте точно сколько дней у вас подразумевается в одном месяце и вычитайте количество дней

Comment: @АлексейШиманский особенности чего? мозга?

Comment: @Igor работы с датами в языке очевидно

Comment: @Igor "getMonth() Получить месяц, от 0 до 11.", somedate.getMonth() = 9, somedate.setMonth(9 - 1)

Comment: "Один месяц" это сколько времени?  Понятно же, что изменив номер месяца на единицу для 31-го октября, мы получим недействительное сочетание месяца и дня.

Comment: @Igor не сообразил что Автоисправление делает 1 октября, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя `getMonth() - 1` Вы пытаетесь установить несуществующую дату, 31 сентября. Т.к. последнее число в сентябре 30, остается 1 день, который устанавливает следующую дату `(getMonth() - 1) + 1 Day`.

Чтобы избежать подобной проблемы используйте второй параметр, [dayValue](https://javascript.ru/date/setmonth).

```
var somedate = new Date();
console.log(somedate);
somedate.setMonth(somedate.getMonth() - 1, 30);
console.log(somedate);
somedate.setDate(1);
console.log(somedate);
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/svbvyhff/)

**UPD**: для удобства можете создать массив с количеством дней в каждом месяце:

```
// пример для последних чисел месяца
var monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var monthDaysV = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]; //кол-во дней в месяцах високосного года
var somedate = new Date(2017, 09, 31);
var monthLeft = 1;
console.log(somedate);
var prev_month = somedate.getMonth() - monthLeft;
var year = (prev_month < 0) ? ( somedate.getFullYear() - 1 ) : somedate.getFullYear();

if(!((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
{ //невисокосный год
  somedate.setMonth(prev_month, monthDays[prev_month]);
}
else
{ //високосный год
  somedate.setMonth(prev_month, monthDaysV[prev_month]);
}
console.log(somedate);
somedate.setDate(1);
console.log(somedate);
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kjzLondt/)

Comment: дабы избежать проблем в марте с февралем, можно выставить     28, и вообще любую дату?

Comment: Опять "дабы"!? Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, почему все вдруг стали говорить "дабы"?

Comment: В феврале еще бывает 29 дней

Comment: @ArtGrek13 если месяц до которого будет сдвиг есть февраль, то да ставите 28

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, нужно поставить проверку на високосный год, я как пример показал

Comment: @Igor не знаю, на автомате,  это не подходящее слово?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Я вырос во времена, когда говорили "чтобы". А сейчас население России перешло на высокий слог?

Comment: @Igor я в принципе тоже и в жизни так не говорю, на форумах подцепил)